# Calculating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (r e^{2 \pi i \alpha})^{n!}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$.

Tags: complex-numbers, power-series

I need to calculate $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (r e^{2 \pi i \alpha})^{n!}$ for $\alpha \in \mathbb Q$ and $r \in \mathbb R$.

My Attempt:

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (r e^{2 \pi i \alpha})^{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r e^{2 \pi i \alpha n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r (\cos (2 \pi \alpha n!) + i \sin (2 \pi \alpha n!)),$
and I'm stuck here, I think I should use a trigonometric identity to deal with the $\cos$ and $\sin$ of $2 \pi \alpha n!$, but I don't know which identity I could use.

Comment: There's a slight typo, $(re^{2\pi i\alpha})^{n!}=r^{n!}e^{2\pi i \alpha n!}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha=p/q$ and $n\ge q$ then $\alpha n!$ is an integer and so
$$(re^{2\pi i\alpha})^{n!}=r^{n!}\ .$$
So the tail of the sum is
$$r^{q!}+r^{(q+1)!}+r^{(q+2)!}+\cdots\ ;$$
this diverges if $|r|\ge1$.  It converges if $|r|<1$, but I don't know of any simple expression for the sum.

Comment: If $|r|<1$ it converges to a trascendental number, by a theorem of Liouville